# Find the smallest value at x=25

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

A function g: is called adjective if $g(m)+g(n)>max(m^2,n^2)$  for any pair of integers m and n. Let f be an adjective function such that the value of $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+...+f(30)$ is minimized. Find the smallest possible value of $f(25)$.

My approach: -
$\\
f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+...+f(30) \\
= (f(1)+f(30))+(f(2)+f(29))+...+(f(15)+f(16)) \\
\geq 30^2+1+29^2+1+...16^2+1$

If minimized, $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+...+f(30)= \Sigma_{i=16}^{30}(i^2+1)$

Now, if $j\in {1,2,..,15}$ and $i\in {1,2,..,15}, f(j)+f(i) \geq i^2+1$

After that, how can I approach the problem?

Comment: +1 to your question.  Nice presentation and reasonable work shown on what looks like a complicated problem.  However, consider that $~[f(1) + f(7)] \geq 50,~$ while $~[f(1) + f(30)] \geq 901, ~[f(7) + f(23) \geq 530.~$ I don't see how you can find $f(25)$ without first finding the actual minimum for $f(1) + \cdots + f(30)$, demonstrating by example that this assignment of $f(1), \cdots, f(30)$ satisfies all necessary constraints, and **also** proving that the assignment results in a minimum.  ...see next comment

Comment: Even then, with a (feasible) minimum established, you would have to find all possible values of $f(25)$ that preserve this minimum.  This problem is no walk in the park.

Comment: What is the source of this problem, and what is your math background?

Comment: The problem appeared in 2021 Bangladesh National Olympiad (BDMO). I am pursuing Bachelor's in Mathematics.

Comment: If I was attacking this problem, I would use a computer program to brute force compute the minimum sum of $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$, with (for example) $n = 4, n = 5, n= 6$.  Then, I would look for a pattern in the data and try to formulate and prove a hypothesis, based on this data.

Comment: That might be a good idea to consider, I am little slow with coding though.

Comment: Solution here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2541137p21658014

Comment: @TheBestMagician Hey, thanks for that one.